# How to change folder icons in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I know that there is a plugin that helps to change the jobs icon, or add your own. But how can I change the folder icons in Jenkins?

I am using **"Folders Plugin"** and there I have only: "Default", "Github Organization Avatar" and "Github Repository Icon". Is there some plugin that can help me?

Answer (score 2):

The 'Cloudbees Folders Plugin' only allows plugins to interact with these icons. If you press the Help button next to the "Icon" field on a folder, the info is displayed:

> "A folder can have an icon of your choosing. Aside from static icons that can be used to visually distinguish different folders, plugins can implement more sophisticated icons that change their graphics depending on what the folder contains."

Cloudbees has a Folder Plus plugin that allows custom icons to be specified, either by uploading a file or providing a URL to an available image. This plugin and feature is currently exclusive to the hosted Jenkins Cloudbees environment. Info here: https://go.cloudbees.com/docs/cloudbees-documentation/cje-user-guide/index.html#folders-plus-sect-icons

Comment: Is it only for Jenkins enterprise edition and not for the free one? Or am I missing something?